# SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.TblDepartments'. Table name pluralized

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC with a SQL Server database and a `TblDepartment`.

When I load the Register page, I get an error is:

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.TblDepartments'

In all my code, I refer to the table as `TblDepartment`, but the error came out with `TblDepartments` (with an `s` at the end).

Now, when I renamed the `TblDepartment` to `TblDepartments` in SQL Server, everything works ok. Has anyone ever seen this kind of issue?

This is my code:

TblDepartment.cs

```
namespace WebApp1.Models
{
    public class TblDepartment
    {
        [Key]
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AccountViewModels.cs

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeptId")]
    public TblDepartment TblDepartment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

IdentityModels.cs

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TblDepartment> TblDepartment { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Register.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeptId", null, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

AccountController.cs

```
// GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.DeptId = new SelectList(db.TblDepartment.ToList(), "DeptId", "DeptName");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Check the migration files for the table reference. What does this say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework automatically adds "S" to SQL Server Table Name. The EF uses  [PluralizingTableNameConvention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.pluralizingtablenameconvention(v=vs.113).aspx) rules for table names.

You can explicitly set table name using [TableMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables)

1. You can use Data Annotations to configure the table that a type maps to

   ```
   [Table(Name = "TblDepartment")]
   public class TblDepartment
   {
       [Key]
       public int DeptId { get; set; }
       public string DeptName { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. You can use the Fluent API to configure the table that a type maps to.

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<TblDepartment>()
            .ToTable("TblDepartment");
   }
   ```

Another option you can turn off EF pluralization convention

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I end up pluralizing all the table name, this solved the problem.